# Submit handler, React Axios: Post and Get in same handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, axios

I am trying to create a web app that uploads file and attached the current user to the file model as a foreign key. For some reason the get request is being wiped, but it does initially get the needed information.

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/current_user/', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      }
    }).then((user) => {

      this.state.creator = user.data;
      console.log(this.state.creator);
    })  
    console.log(this.state.creator);
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('creator', this.state.creator);
    form_data.append('file', this.state.file);
    form_data.append('title', this.state.title);
    form_data.append('description', this.state.description);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/core/posts/', form_data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  };
```

The 1st console is returning the user information but the 2nd console returns null. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `then` statement after the original `get` ends on line 11, and the rest of your code is outside of that.

With asynchronous code, the code outside of the `then` block will continue running while it's waiting for a response, so `this.state.creator` will not have been set yet. Then it will return to the code inside the `then` block once the promise resolves.

You need to move all of the second block of code inside the intial `then` block so it is only executed once a response to the original `get` request has returned:

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios
    .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/current_user/', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    })
    .then((user) => {
      this.state.creator = user.data;
      console.log(this.state.creator);
      let form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append('creator', this.state.creator);
      form_data.append('file', this.state.file);
      form_data.append('title', this.state.title);
      form_data.append('description', this.state.description);
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:8000/core/posts/', form_data, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
};
```